# three.js - how to make camera look at an object during a tween

Tags: javascript, canvas, 3d, webgl, three.js

so I'm experimenting with using tweens to tween a camera's fov based on an object that is clicked on in the scene, which is working great, but now what I want it to do is to have the camera switch its focus to the object that was clicked, which is not working. Here's my code for the click:

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
    var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( objects );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) { //We've clicked a certain object

        camTarget = intersects[0].object.position; //HERE'S THE VECTOR3 I WANT TO LOOK AT
        camTween.start();
    }
}
```

and my code for the tween / camera movement:

```
var camUpdate = function(){
    camera.fov = currentFov.fov;  //WORKING
    camera.lookAt(camTarget); //NOT WORKING
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}

var currentFov = { fov: camera.fov };

TWEEN.removeAll();
camTween = new TWEEN.Tween(currentFov).to({fov: +zoomInFov},tweenTime).easing(camEase).onUpdate(camUpdate);
```

The camera is tweening the field of view properly, but it appears to stay pointed in the same direction it always was pointed at, instead of switching to the "camTarget" vector specified in the lookAt command.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The renderer calls THREE.Camera.update(), which sets the rotation of the camera by default to look at THREE.Camera.target (which is an THREE.Object3D). Instead of doing...

```
camera.lookAt( camTarget );
```

...try...

```
camera.target.position.copy( camTarget );
```

I'm not sure I follow how camTarget is tweened, or maybe it just should switch to the new object?

Side note: it's advisable not to perform heavy computation in event handlers - in the best of worlds, you set a flag in the event handler and process in the render loop.

Comment: Ah - yeah, the problem of getting it to look at the proper location was that I put it in the event handler, not the animate loop. I was able to use lookAt() and not copy(). Nice catch. As far as how it will be tweened, I'm not sure. I thought that by putting it in an animate function, as the camera moved its fov, the lookAt function would change dynamically as well, making it look, in a sense, as if it were tweening. I suppose I might have to actually move the camera rather than change the fov for that to work. Thanks again though.

Comment: @MikaelEmtinger - why should you not do too much in the event handler?

Answer (score 8):

Sadly, as of three.js version 112 in Feb 2020, camera.target no longer works.  jb

Comment: This is absolutely driving me crazy. Everytime I find a useful function in THREEjs that would make my life easier I find out it's deprecated!! Why the HELL would they deprecate this without offering an alternative?? Do I now have to find a way to rotate the camera so that it is always looking at the target manually?

Comment: Have you tried LookAt ? jb